# Firebase Auth/unauthorized domain. Domain is not authorized ---What should i do..?

Tags: firebase, authentication, error-handling, console, project

I am trying to run this sample firebase project, but I keep getting this error in the browser console.

message: "Error: auth/unauthorized-domain"